# My question is on-topic here, isn't it?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I posted the following question yesterday:

[Automatically fill From: field and add today's date in email's body, with Gmail Canned Responses](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/114789/automatically-fill-from-field-and-add-todays-date-in-emails-body-with-gmail)

I was initially unsure if this would fit WA or SU, but being about Gmail and not about a web browser extension for Gmail and/or developing a web app, I thought posting it on SU would be wrong. Did I make the right choice?

Comment: Please checkout [help/on-topic]

Comment: @Rubén thanks for the suggestion. It's precisely because I read that page, that I thought the post to be on-topic. Since this is my first post, I just wanted to double check with some more expert user that my understanding was correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your question is on-topic here. You might want to look at some of the other questions tagged [gmail-canned-response](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-canned-response); other folks have asked similar questions.

You might want to break your post up into smaller paragraphs to make it a bit easier to read online.

Comment: thanks, I'll follow both suggestions.